# Conection Failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in godaddy cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have hosted my website on godaddy cpanel and database in cpanel but when i try to login it show me the message

> Connection Failed: Access denied for user 'medmocksroot'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

I have also tried this by renaming the username and password according to cpanel username and password but still it showing same error..... please help me out

my php page:

```php
<?php
require_once 'sessions.php';

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "medmocksroot";
$password = "medmocks123";
$dbname = "medmocks";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

Comment: Without any code we are not able to help you to diagnose your issue(s).

Comment: "password: NO" well thats the problem

Comment: In Connection file you have to add database user and password not cpanel username, password.